# Sails-Memory data issues

Tags: node.js, sails.js, in-memory-database

I'm using 'sails-memory' for storing users once they login.
On logout I am trying to destroy the user from In memory.

User Socket Model:

```
attributes: {
 userId: 'string',
 companyId:'string',
 socketId:'string',
 rooms: {
    collection: 'socketRooms',
    via: 'users',
    dominant: true
 }  
}
```

Create Method :

```
UserSocket.create({
        userId : user.id,
        socketId : socketId,
        companyId : user.company
    }).exec(function(err, userSocket) { ... });
```

Destroy User Socket:

```
UserSocket.destroy({id:user.id}).exec(function(){ ... });
```

Question 1: Is there any interface where we can view all data stored in `Sails-Memory`?
Question 2: Currently I am using `migrate: drop` in model which clears all sails memory data related to model on sails lift. Is it good to use `migrate: drop`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The sails-memory is "An in-memory object store which works great as a bundled, starter database (with the strict caveat that it is for non-production use only)". It doesn't matter what you put in migrate since when the app finishes all the data is discarded anyway.

And to get access to the data you can just use the default rest service (if you haven't disabled it), so if your model is called "something" you should be able to get all the data on localhost:1337/something/